# How to secure Mac laptop while it is running processes such as wget, or some local node.js apps?

Tags: macos, security, login, multitasking

I would like my computer to continue running processes until they're done. I typically just keep my laptop on, but if I leave turn it off. How can I leave though and *secure it* (like log off or something) while still keeping the code running? Does the code automatically continue running?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "Lock Screen" feature is your friend:

[image]

all of your processes will continue to run, but your password will be needed to access anything.

Command+Control+Q if you need to dash off quickly.